# How to programmatically add Facets to PanelBox in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf, programmatically-created, facet

I have a requirement in which i have to dynamically add facets to a panel box layout and then add elements to the same such as text and buttons.

I have searched multiple forums but to no avail.

I have tried the following code as well:

```
RichPanelBox panelBox=new RichPanelBox();
panelBox.getFacet("top").getChildren().add(Button);
```

but this returns with null pointer exception as

```
panelBox.getFacet("top")
```

is null.

any pointers how can i add facet( tag in Jspx) to the panelbox programmatically..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The panelBox doesn't have a top facet.
There is a toolbar facet.
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_panelBox.html

So you should just add a child layout component into the af:panelBox that will give you the breakdown of layout you need in the box.

Comment: Thanks Shay..I realized my mistake...i should have added Panel Border Layout first to the PanelBox...It has methods for adding facets..:)